# Logging a list of Worker Process Requests when Application Recycle happens

Tags: windows-event-log, iis

Does anyone know of the best way to log all work process requests that are currently running when an IIS recycle happens.

If you go to IIS > Worker Processes > Select an app pool > View Current Requests you get a list of requests.

We have occasional recycles. If we are able to see the RAM on the server for w3wp.exe going up quickly, and we check the list of requests, we are often able to pinpoint the source of the issue (the URL gives us enough info to go on).

We have logEventOnRecycle set to log the event, and this works, but the details are useless.

In a perfect world the list of requests would go into the details of the event log.

In an even more perfect world, our team would get the requests emailed to us on a recycle.

Anyone else ever walk down this path?

Answer (score 1):

Try DebugDiag tool, it's by far the easiest one to use that's free from MS. It's easy to setup to catch crash/hang and gives you a decent way to review the contents of it's dump files. It's pointed us right to the source in the code several times.

Here is a quick setup article, [Steps to Catch a Simple “Crash Dump” of a Crashing Process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2013/11/12/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process.aspx) from an MS blogger.

It's worth a try to see if you can catch what's causing your recycles.